# How to cluster using kMeans in Weka?

Tags: java, weka, k-means

I have a set of text documents in a folder, which I need to cluster using weka in a java program. 
But using *TextDirectoryLoader* to convert the document set into an *Instances* object gives a format which has *class* as an attribute.  When this is used for clustering, throws a WekaException  *weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans: Cannot handle any class attribute!*.

How do I convert a set of documents into Instances that can be clustered by Weka's SimpleKMeans?

Comment: Your best bet would most likely be to convert it into an ARFF file. See [here](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) for a good tutorial.

Comment: Remove the class attribute?

Comment: I am not expert on weka but  as I know clustering does not need class attribute, you should not set classIndex on the Instances object or you can set to negative value to show there is no class.